# How to create an external shadow at the top of my layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-linearlayout, shadow

I want to create External Shadow at the top of a view in Android.

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout2"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

How to make shadow in the external Top of the layout `layout1`?

Answer (score 0):

use elevation property in your layout:

```
android:elevation="3dp"
```

Comment: Please include more context if possible. Perhaps screenshot of LinearLayout with shadow helps.